# I'm trying to set Default Calendar Permission in Exchange 2016 on prem, to AvailabilityOnly

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

Newbie here, sorry in advance if this is unclear.

I need to set default calendar permissions to AvailabilityOnly in Exchange 2016, based off of group membership in AD. "I think" i'm getting crossed up because I'm using an AD class to retrieve the users from the group, but when I try to use the array to apply the changes in exchange, I keep getting an error:

> parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the
>   "@{userPrincipalName=JohnDoe@ourdomain.com}" value  of type
>   "Deserialized.Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser" to
>   type 
>   "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxFolderIdParameter".

How can I avoid/get around this error in Powershell 5.0.

I'm using `Get-ADGroupMember` then getting the `UserPrincipalName` with `Get-AdUser`, then packing all the userprincipalname's into an array to be used in the `-identity` property of `set-mailboxfolderpermission`.

I'm getting multiple users from different groups and packaging them in an array as so...

```
$Array1 = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "AD Group1" | %{get-aduser $_.SamAccountName | select userPrincipalName} 

$Array2 = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "AD Group2" | %{get-aduser $_.SamAccountName | select userPrincipalName} 

$upn=array1+array2
```

during testing, I print to make sure I'm getting the strings I want.

```
$upn

user1@ourdomain.com

user2@ourdomain.com

user3@ourdomain.com
```

So far so good.

When I try to update the accounts as so....

```
Foreach ($employee in $upn) {
    Set-MailboxFolderPermission -AccessRights AvailabilityOnly *-Identity $employee* -User default
}
```

which again returns the error

> parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the
>   "@{userPrincipalName=JohnDoe@ourdomain.com}" value  of type
>   "Deserialized.Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser" to
>   type 
>   "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxFolderIdParameter".

Answer (score 0):

The `-Identity` parameter expects  folder name.  The folder name should be :.

So, if you had a user with john.smith@domain.com, the command should be:

```bsh
Set-MailboxFolderPermissions -Identity john.smith@domain.com:\Calendar -AccessRights AvailabilityOnly -User Default
```

To make this work for your example:

```bsh
ForEach ($employee in $upn) {
    Set-MailboxFolderPermissions -Identity ${employee}:\Calendar -AccessRights AvailabilityOnly -User Default

}
```

*The {} isn't necessary, but it helps to clearly define what is the variable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/set-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps

Comment: So I tried what you've described, but i'm still getting an error;
The specified mailbox "@{userPrincipalName=joeuser@yourdomain.com}" doesn't exist.

Comment: @Shootinst8 are you sure the mailbox exists?  Do ```Get-Mailbox user@domain.com```.  It could be that it is some recipient type besides a mailbox, which wouldn’t work.

Comment: Try running the cmdlet directly rather than through the ForEach loop to troubleshoot it.  The only ways it should fail: 1) not a valid mailbox (which your error indicates), or 2) you don't have permissions

Also, if you're in a multi-domain forest, you would have to set the options to show recipients in all domains: ```Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $True```

Comment: @Dustn yes, I've double checked it. Single domain forest. running as domain admin